# Java Array String[] name or String name[]

Tags: java, arrays

I have a small question.

Is there any differences between:
  - String[] name
  and 
  String name[]

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing, both works but the second one is discouraged.
The first one:

```
String[] myStringArray;
```

Is the default and the most used.